# Windows Phone 8 Unit Test App FileNotFoundException

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that I'm trying to unit test. I added a Windows Phone Unit Test App to my project and added a reference to my Windows Phone project. When I try to debug a test in the emulator or my device, I get a FileNotFoundException. It errors in the unit test's MainPage.xaml.cs when it tries to instantiate a TestExecutorServiceWrapper.

It seems like I'm missing some references, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Exception Message:

> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

> Exception:
>   {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>      at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
>      at vstest_executionengine_platformbridge.MessageTransmitter..ctor()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.TestExecutorServiceWrapper..ctor()
>      at WinPhoneApp.UnitTests.MainPage..ctor()}
>
> Stack Trace:
>       at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
>       at vstest_executionengine_platformbridge.MessageTransmitter..ctor()
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.TestExecutorServiceWrapper..ctor()
>       at WinPhoneApp.UnitTests.MainPage..ctor()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well.  I found some good info here: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2013/06/x86arm-configuration-gotcha-in-windows.html

Short story: The Windows Phone 8 Unit Test app project is a platform specific project (x86 for the emulator, ARM for the actual device).  My WP8 project was AnyCPU, so when I added the test project I tried to make the test project AnyCPU to match my main settings and that resulted in this error.

Adding a config for testing the phone project (as suggested by the blog post linked) solved my problem and my tests now run fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't find out what was the issue with my test project, but I did get it working. I ended up adding a new Unit Test app to my project. I ran the default unit test that is added to a unit test project. It ran fine and there were no FileNotFoundException. So I started adding all my references, including the NuGet references, checking that the unit test ran on each change. Then one by one, I started adding each of the classes in my old unit test app to the new unit test app, and testing the default unit test with each change. After adding all the classes to the new testing project, I didn't get any errors.

So the bad news is I don't know what caused the initial error, but at least I got my new unit test project working.